# How to convert JSON object to XML in UTF-8 format

Tags: java, xml, json, jakarta-ee, utf-8

I am trying to convert a JSON object to an XML document.

Below is the code,noting that I want to output the XML in **UTF-8** format.

```
package com.test.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class ConvertJSONtoXML {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader jsonBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\sample-json.json")));
    String line = null;
    String json="";
    while( (line=jsonBuffer.readLine())!=null){
      json+=line; // here we have all json loaded
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

    System.out.println(XML.toString(jsonObject)); // here we have XML Code

    jsonBuffer.close();

  }
}
```

Can anyone please help on this. I have JSON data in **Thai** character.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using `FileReader` to start with - that will always use the platform default encoding. Use `InputStreamReader` with a specific encoding. Oh, and don't perform string concatenation in a loop like that...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to java. Can you please guide how to do that..

Comment: Which part? Have you looked at the documentation for `InputStreamReader`? Also note that as you're writing to the console, it may not support all the characters you want... to writing it to a file instead (using `OutputStreamWriter`, and specifying UTF-8 as the encoding).

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString())...This line throws an error saying "no suitable constructor found for JSONObject(String)"

Answer (score 0):

Update your class to use an `InputStreamReader` instead of `FileReader` because `InputStreamReader`s can take the encoding charset as a second constructor argument:

```
public class ConvertJSONtoXML
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    File jsonFile = new File("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\sample-json.json");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(jsonFile), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader jsonBuffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = jsonBuffer.readLine()) != null)
    {
      json.append(line); // here we have all json loaded
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());
    System.out.println(XML.toString(jsonObject)); // here we have XML Code
    jsonBuffer.close();
  }
}
```

---

The code has been also updated to use a `StringBuilder` for json tokens concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't post the code here. I have edited the original question. I have limitation to post the code while answering as I am new to this forum. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: Can you provide what you got as an output? The *???* marks appears in the console?
I can successfully transform the file you have provided as json enry.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to write xml in a file with a uTF-8 but the problem is its only printing the first object of json. It should iterate and convert all the object of json into xml file.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString())...This line throws an error saying "no suitable constructor found for JSONObject(String)"

Comment: Make sure to use the `org.json.JSONObject` class type.